# Can't find the menu for adding an usb game controller

Tags: usb, setup, retropie

A couple weeks back I was setting up my pi and going through a ton of info about setting it up and I remember coming across a menu to set up USB game controllers (the USB human interface device).

This menu looked very similar to the menu that comes up when you input `sudo raspi-config` but with an option that says "configure USB controller" or something along those lines.

Does anyone know the command to bring up this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging I found what I was after:

```
cd RetroPie-Setup
chmod +x retropie_setup.sh
sudo ./retropie_setup.sh
```

This gave me the setup menu and I was able to choose the option to configure a USB controller.

Comment: @WernerVesterås I have to wait 3 hours :'( haha